# How to access SQL Server Analysis Service Instance remotely that is from another computer?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am stuck in two problems mentioned below::

**1.**   SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS) is installed on my local machine. Default instance of SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) is running and its default port is 2383. Now, I want to access that SQL Server Analysis Services(SSAS) instance from another computer which is on different network. I access database Engine instance from another computer using SQL Server authentication. I did this by following the procedure like port forwarding, defining inbound rules in windows firewall setting etc. I followed the same procedure for accessing SQL Server Analysis Services(SSAS) instance but SQL Server Analysis Services(SSAS) is not supporting SQL server authentication mode. How can I do this?

**2.**      SQL Server Analysis Services instance is running on my local machine. I want someone from another network to deploy a cube on my local machine using SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) via internet. How can he access my analysis service database? What are the settings I must do to allow him to connect to my Analysis Services database?

Thanks

Comment: You can only access an SSAS instance via Windows Authentication; if the external user cannot authenticate to your domain (most likely via a VPN), then they cannot connect to the SSAS. If they can, then the process is trivial, due to how VPNs work. So implement a VPN if you don't already have one.

Comment: [HTTP access](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0) is not restricted to Windows users.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Larnu, i haven't implemented VPN yet. It don't have much knowledge of how VPN works. it would be thankful if you suggest some useful resources.